# Extruder temp is too high

Tags: simplify3d, heat-management

I am using Simplify3d software to print my first object, I set the temp to 230, but I notice that the temp some times reaches to 300 c, any help, here is temp plot
[image]
here is the communication code of last process

```
SENT: G1 X190.134 Y143.078 E11.6837
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.230 Y157.981 E12.6300
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.239 Y158.007 E12.6312
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.399 Y158.378 E12.6494
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X190.541 Y143.236 E13.6109
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X190.928 Y143.415 E13.6301
READ: ok T:224 @:193 B:0
SENT: G1 X175.569 Y158.774 E14.6054
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.618 Y158.887 E14.6109
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.759 Y159.150 E14.6243
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X191.315 Y143.594 E15.6122
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X191.702 Y143.772 E15.6313
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.955 Y159.519 E16.6312
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.069 Y159.733 E16.6421
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.163 Y159.878 E16.6498
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.627 Y143.413 E17.6953
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.910 Y143.696 E17.7133
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok T:225 @:191 B:0
SENT: G1 X176.384 Y160.222 E18.7627
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.588 Y160.538 E18.7796
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.608 Y160.564 E18.7810
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X193.283 Y143.889 E19.8398
READ: ok T:227 @:205 B:0
SENT: G1 X193.869 Y143.868 E19.8662
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.854 Y160.883 E20.9467
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X177.100 Y161.203 E20.9648
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X194.403 Y143.900 E22.0636
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X194.520 Y143.918 E22.0689
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X194.728 Y143.970 E22.0785
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X194.854 Y144.014 E22.0845
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X177.362 Y161.507 E23.1953
READ: ok T:227 @:143 B:0
SENT: G1 X177.631 Y161.804 E23.2132
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.239 Y144.196 E24.3314
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.313 Y144.239 E24.3352
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.460 Y144.347 E24.3434
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.562 Y144.438 E24.3495
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X177.909 Y162.091 E25.4705
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X178.202 Y162.364 E25.4885
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.825 Y144.741 E26.6075
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.862 Y144.792 E26.6103
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok T:231 @:120 B:0
SENT: G1 X195.957 Y144.955 E26.6188
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.026 Y145.105 E26.6262
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X178.495 Y162.636 E27.7394
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X178.519 Y162.659 E27.7409
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X178.810 Y162.887 E27.7575
READ: ok T:233 @:146 B:0
SENT: G1 X196.164 Y145.533 E28.8595
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.178 Y145.587 E28.8620
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.213 Y145.810 E28.8721
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.230 Y146.033 E28.8822
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.127 Y163.136 E29.9682
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.273 Y163.251 E29.9766
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.456 Y163.372 E29.9864
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.210 Y146.619 E31.0503
READ: ok T:236 @:97 B:0
SENT: G1 X196.196 Y146.982 E31.0666
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.304 Y147.090 E31.0735
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.797 Y163.597 E32.1217
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X180.072 Y163.779 E32.1365
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X180.143 Y163.817 E32.1401
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.587 Y147.373 E33.1843
READ: ok T:235 @:88 B:0
SENT: G1 X196.745 Y147.531 E33.1943
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.129 Y148.146 E33.2334
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.206 Y148.320 E33.2419
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X180.508 Y164.017 E34.2387
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X180.874 Y164.217 E34.2574
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.379 Y148.712 E35.2420
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.553 Y149.104 E35.2613
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X181.263 Y164.394 E36.2321
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X181.655 Y164.568 E36.2514
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.726 Y149.497 E37.2084
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok T:237 @:66 B:0
SENT: G1 X196.793 Y149.648 E37.2158
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.882 Y149.906 E37.2281
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X182.065 Y164.723 E38.1690
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X182.485 Y164.869 E38.1889
READ: ok T:239 @:50 B:0
SENT: G1 X197.027 Y150.327 E39.1124
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.106 Y150.555 E39.1232
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.159 Y150.761 E39.1328
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X182.919 Y165.001 E40.0370
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X183.368 Y165.117 E40.0578
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.274 Y151.211 E40.9409
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.344 Y151.484 E40.9535
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.376 Y151.675 E40.9622
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X183.834 Y165.217 E41.8221
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X184.317 Y165.299 E41.8441
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.457 Y152.159 E42.6785
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.503 Y152.430 E42.6908
READ: ok T:240 @:15 B:0
SENT: G1 X197.522 Y152.660 E42.7012
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X184.819 Y165.363 E43.5078
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X185.340 Y165.408 E43.5313
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.566 Y153.182 E44.3077
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.583 Y153.385 E44.3169
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.584 Y153.730 E44.3323
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X185.889 Y165.425 E45.0750
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X186.453 Y165.427 E45.1003
READ: ok T:243 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X197.584 Y154.295 E45.8071
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.584 Y154.344 E45.8094
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.538 Y154.907 E45.8347
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X187.065 Y165.380 E46.4997
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X187.435 Y165.350 E46.5164
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X187.705 Y165.306 E46.5287
READ: ok T:244 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X197.465 Y155.546 E47.1484
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.352 Y156.225 E47.1793
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X188.382 Y165.195 E47.7489
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X189.137 Y165.005 E47.7839
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.163 Y156.980 E48.2935
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.113 Y157.176 E48.3026
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.893 Y157.814 E48.3329
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X189.970 Y164.738 E48.7725
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X190.047 Y164.712 E48.7762
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X190.214 Y164.653 E48.7841
READ: ok T:244 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X190.935 Y164.339 E48.8194
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.496 Y158.778 E49.1726
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.415 Y158.961 E49.1816
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.958 Y159.804 E49.2246
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.812 Y160.027 E49.2366
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.188 Y163.651 E49.4668
READ: ok T:247 @:0 B:0
SENT: G92 E0
SENT: G1 E-1.0000 F1800
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.126 Y164.098 F3600
READ: ok
SENT: G1 Z0.870 F1000
READ: ok
SENT: G1 E0.0000 F1800
READ: ok
SENT: G92 E0
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X191.259 Y164.568 E0.0443 F1875
READ: ok
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X190.356 Y164.963 E0.0886
SENT: G1 X189.423 Y165.283 E0.1328
READ: ok
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X188.467 Y165.524 E0.1771
READ: ok T:249 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X187.494 Y165.686 E0.2214
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X186.510 Y165.766 E0.2657
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X186.164 Y165.768 E0.2813
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X185.527 Y165.765 E0.3099
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X184.544 Y165.682 E0.3542
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X183.571 Y165.518 E0.3985
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X182.616 Y165.274 E0.4427
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X181.684 Y164.952 E0.4870
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X180.782 Y164.554 E0.5313
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.914 Y164.081 E0.5756
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.624 Y163.893 E0.5912
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.094 Y163.541 E0.6197
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X178.316 Y162.933 E0.6641
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X177.593 Y162.263 E0.7083
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.928 Y161.535 E0.7526
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.323 Y160.753 E0.7970
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.133 Y160.464 E0.8125
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.790 Y159.929 E0.8411
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.323 Y159.059 E0.8854
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.931 Y158.154 E0.9297
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.615 Y157.220 E0.9739
READ: ok
SENT: M105
SENT: G1 X174.377 Y156.263 E1.0182
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.220 Y155.290 E1.0625
READ: ok
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.143 Y154.304 E1.1069
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.141 Y153.958 E1.1224
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.148 Y153.323 E1.1509
READ: ok T:250 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X174.235 Y152.339 E1.1953
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.403 Y151.368 E1.2396
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.651 Y150.413 E1.2838
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.976 Y149.483 E1.3281
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.378 Y148.583 E1.3724
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.855 Y147.715 E1.4168
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.042 Y147.425 E1.4323
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.396 Y146.898 E1.4608
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X177.009 Y146.123 E1.5052
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X177.690 Y145.393 E1.5500
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X177.735 Y145.349 E1.5528
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X178.478 Y144.684 E1.5976
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.266 Y144.089 E1.6419
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X180.101 Y143.562 E1.6863
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X180.976 Y143.105 E1.7306
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X181.886 Y142.723 E1.7749
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X182.825 Y142.418 E1.8192
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X183.786 Y142.191 E1.8636
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X184.763 Y142.045 E1.9079
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X185.748 Y141.980 E1.9523
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X186.735 Y141.997 E1.9966
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X187.717 Y142.096 E2.0409
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X188.688 Y142.276 E2.0852
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X189.641 Y142.536 E2.1296
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X190.568 Y142.874 E2.1739
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X191.867 Y143.474 E2.2381
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.518 Y142.823 E2.2795
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X193.105 Y143.410 E2.3167
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X193.821 Y143.318 E2.3492
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X194.266 Y143.309 E2.3691
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X194.514 Y143.327 E2.3803
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X194.805 Y143.374 E2.3936
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.033 Y143.431 E2.4041
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.292 Y143.522 E2.4164
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.490 Y143.613 E2.4262
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.716 Y143.745 E2.4379
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.883 Y143.867 E2.4473
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.072 Y144.038 E2.4587
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.210 Y144.191 E2.4679
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.362 Y144.398 E2.4795
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.469 Y144.581 E2.4890
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.581 Y144.824 E2.5010
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.655 Y145.036 E2.5111
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.724 Y145.312 E2.5239
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.762 Y145.553 E2.5348
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.785 Y145.855 E2.5484
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.779 Y146.212 E2.5644
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.685 Y146.990 E2.5996
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.225 Y147.531 E2.6340
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.534 Y148.222 E2.6779
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.110 Y149.524 E2.7418
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.432 Y150.457 E2.7861
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.676 Y151.413 E2.8304
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.841 Y152.387 E2.8748
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.923 Y153.371 E2.9191
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.924 Y154.358 E2.9634
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.843 Y155.342 E3.0078
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.681 Y156.316 E3.0521
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.439 Y157.273 E3.0964
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.118 Y158.207 E3.1408
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.721 Y159.111 E3.1851
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.250 Y159.979 E3.2294
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.709 Y160.805 E3.2737
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.101 Y161.583 E3.3181
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X194.454 Y162.285 E3.3610
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X193.729 Y162.953 E3.4052
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.950 Y163.560 E3.4496
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.661 Y163.751 E3.4651
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.126 Y164.098 E3.4937
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.331 Y164.442 F3600
SENT: G92 E0
READ: ok
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X191.434 Y164.927 E0.0458 F1250
READ: ok
READ: ok
SENT: M105
SENT: G1 X190.501 Y165.336 E0.0915
SENT: G1 X189.537 Y165.667 E0.1373
READ: ok
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X188.549 Y165.916 E0.1830
READ: ok T:252 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X187.543 Y166.083 E0.2288
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X186.527 Y166.166 E0.2746
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X186.164 Y166.168 E0.2909
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X185.509 Y166.165 E0.3203
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X184.493 Y166.079 E0.3661
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X183.488 Y165.909 E0.4118
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X182.501 Y165.657 E0.4576
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X181.538 Y165.324 E0.5034
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X180.606 Y164.913 E0.5491
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.710 Y164.425 E0.5949
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.405 Y164.228 E0.6112
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X178.859 Y163.866 E0.6406
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X178.057 Y163.237 E0.6864
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X177.309 Y162.545 E0.7321
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.621 Y161.793 E0.7779
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.998 Y160.986 E0.8237
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.798 Y160.683 E0.8400
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.445 Y160.131 E0.8694
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.963 Y159.233 E0.9152
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.557 Y158.298 E0.9609
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.231 Y157.333 E1.0067
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X173.985 Y156.344 E1.0524
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X173.822 Y155.338 E1.0982
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X173.743 Y154.321 E1.1440
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X173.741 Y153.958 E1.1603
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X173.749 Y153.303 E1.1897
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X173.838 Y152.287 E1.2355
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.012 Y151.283 E1.2812
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.268 Y150.297 E1.3270
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.604 Y149.335 E1.3727
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.019 Y148.404 E1.4185
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.511 Y147.510 E1.4643
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.708 Y147.206 E1.4806
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.073 Y146.663 E1.5100
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.705 Y145.862 E1.5558
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X177.403 Y145.114 E1.6017
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X177.461 Y145.057 E1.6054
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X178.224 Y144.375 E1.6513
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.038 Y143.760 E1.6971
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.901 Y143.215 E1.7430
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X180.806 Y142.743 E1.7888
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X181.747 Y142.348 E1.8346
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X182.717 Y142.032 E1.8804
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X183.710 Y141.798 E1.9263
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X184.720 Y141.647 E1.9721
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X185.738 Y141.580 E2.0179
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X186.759 Y141.598 E2.0637
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X187.774 Y141.700 E2.1095
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X188.777 Y141.886 E2.1554
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X189.762 Y142.155 E2.2012
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X190.721 Y142.504 E2.2470
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X191.782 Y142.994 E2.2995
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.518 Y142.257 E2.3462
READ: ok
SENT: M105
SENT: G1 X193.249 Y142.988 E2.3926
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X193.791 Y142.918 E2.4172
READ: ok
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X194.276 Y142.909 E2.4390
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X194.561 Y142.930 E2.4518
READ: ok T:252 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X194.886 Y142.982 E2.4666
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.147 Y143.047 E2.4787
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.443 Y143.150 E2.4927
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.676 Y143.258 E2.5042
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.935 Y143.410 E2.5178
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.136 Y143.557 E2.5289
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.355 Y143.755 E2.5422
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.521 Y143.938 E2.5533
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.696 Y144.178 E2.5666
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.824 Y144.395 E2.5779
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.952 Y144.673 E2.5917
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.039 Y144.921 E2.6035
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.116 Y145.232 E2.6179
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.160 Y145.507 E2.6303
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.185 Y145.843 E2.6455
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.179 Y146.239 E2.6633
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.105 Y146.845 E2.6907
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.791 Y147.531 E2.7342
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.011 Y148.311 E2.7838
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.482 Y149.377 E2.8361
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.816 Y150.342 E2.8819
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X198.068 Y151.331 E2.9278
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X198.238 Y152.337 E2.9736
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X198.323 Y153.354 E3.0194
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X198.324 Y154.375 E3.0652
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X198.241 Y155.392 E3.1111
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X198.073 Y156.398 E3.1569
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.823 Y157.388 E3.2027
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.491 Y158.353 E3.2485
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.080 Y159.287 E3.2944
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.594 Y160.184 E3.3402
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.034 Y161.038 E3.3860
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.406 Y161.842 E3.4318
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X194.737 Y162.568 E3.4762
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X193.988 Y163.259 E3.5219
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X193.183 Y163.885 E3.5677
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.880 Y164.085 E3.5840
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.331 Y164.442 E3.6134
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.387 Y163.328 F3600
SENT: G92 E0
READ: ok
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.574 Y160.515 E0.1786 F2000
READ: ok
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.418 Y160.279 E0.1914
SENT: G1 X176.083 Y159.757 E0.2192
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.739 Y159.114 E0.2519
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X180.801 Y164.177 E0.5734
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X180.933 Y164.248 E0.5801
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X181.809 Y164.635 E0.6231
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X181.834 Y164.644 E0.6243
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.269 Y158.079 E1.0412
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.248 Y158.032 E1.0435
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.973 Y157.217 E1.0821
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X182.699 Y164.943 E1.5727
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X182.714 Y164.948 E1.5734
READ: ok
SENT: M105
SENT: G1 X183.460 Y165.138 E1.6080
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.775 Y156.453 E2.1595
READ: ok
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.711 Y156.195 E2.1714
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.639 Y155.752 E2.1916
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X184.159 Y165.272 E2.7962
READ: ok T:252 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X184.586 Y165.344 E2.8156
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X184.817 Y165.364 E2.8260
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.545 Y155.092 E3.4782
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.498 Y154.479 E3.5058
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X185.434 Y165.416 E4.2003
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X185.542 Y165.425 E4.2052
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X186.012 Y165.427 E4.2262
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.482 Y153.897 E4.9584
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.488 Y153.340 E4.9834
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.488 Y153.338 E4.9835
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X186.570 Y165.420 E5.7507
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X187.093 Y165.377 E5.7742
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.534 Y152.818 E6.5717
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.573 Y152.383 E6.5914
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.586 Y152.305 E6.5949
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X187.604 Y165.323 E7.4216
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X188.089 Y165.242 E7.4436
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.669 Y151.822 E8.2958
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.736 Y151.440 E8.3133
READ: ok
SENT: M105
SENT: G1 X174.760 Y151.347 E8.3176
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X188.562 Y165.150 E9.1940
READ: ok
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X189.014 Y165.036 E9.2149
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.876 Y150.898 E10.1127
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X174.976 Y150.513 E10.1306
READ: ok T:253 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X174.997 Y150.453 E10.1334
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X189.456 Y164.912 E11.0516
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X189.878 Y164.768 E11.0716
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.144 Y150.034 E12.0072
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.290 Y149.615 E12.0271
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X190.294 Y164.619 E12.9799
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X190.688 Y164.447 E12.9991
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.464 Y149.223 E13.9658
READ: ok
SENT: M140 S60
READ: ok T:259 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X175.639 Y148.832 E13.9851
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X191.081 Y164.274 E14.9656
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X191.109 Y164.262 E14.9670
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X191.450 Y164.077 E14.9844
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X175.833 Y148.460 E15.9761
READ: ok T:257 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X176.034 Y148.095 E15.9948
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X191.817 Y163.879 E16.9970
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X191.953 Y163.806 E17.0039
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.169 Y163.665 E17.0155
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.244 Y147.740 E18.0268
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.326 Y147.612 E18.0336
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.469 Y147.399 E18.0451
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.512 Y163.442 E19.0638
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.751 Y163.284 E19.0767
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X192.846 Y163.210 E19.0821
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.699 Y147.064 E20.1074
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X176.949 Y146.748 E20.1255
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X193.164 Y162.963 E21.1551
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X193.482 Y162.715 E21.1732
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X177.198 Y146.431 E22.2072
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok T:259 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X177.267 Y146.345 E22.2122
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X177.465 Y146.132 E22.2252
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X193.778 Y162.446 E23.2611
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X194.073 Y162.174 E23.2791
READ: ok
SENT: M104 S0 T0
READ: ok T:260 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X177.738 Y145.840 E24.3164
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X177.934 Y145.630 E24.3293
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X177.968 Y145.596 E24.3314
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X178.017 Y145.553 E24.3343
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X194.355 Y161.891 E25.3718
READ: ok T:264 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X194.626 Y161.597 E25.3898
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X178.315 Y145.286 E26.4255
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X178.614 Y145.019 E26.4435
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X194.893 Y161.298 E27.4772
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.141 Y160.980 E27.4953
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X178.930 Y144.769 E28.5247
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.252 Y144.526 E28.5429
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.389 Y160.662 E29.5675
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.432 Y160.607 E29.5707
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.617 Y160.325 E29.5858
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X179.583 Y144.291 E30.6040
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok T:262 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X179.930 Y144.072 E30.6224
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.841 Y159.983 E31.6327
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X195.958 Y159.804 E31.6423
READ: ok T:260 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X196.053 Y159.629 E31.6513
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X180.277 Y143.853 E32.6530
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X180.649 Y143.660 E32.6719
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.252 Y159.263 E33.6626
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.415 Y158.961 E33.6780
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.446 Y158.891 E33.6815
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X181.021 Y143.466 E34.6610
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X181.121 Y143.414 E34.6661
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X181.412 Y143.291 E34.6802
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.619 Y158.498 E35.6459
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.791 Y158.105 E35.6652
READ: ok T:262 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X181.810 Y143.124 E36.6165
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X182.005 Y143.042 E36.6259
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X182.223 Y142.971 E36.6362
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X196.938 Y157.686 E37.5706
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.082 Y157.265 E37.5906
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X182.650 Y142.832 E38.5071
READ: ok T:262 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X182.917 Y142.745 E38.5197
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X183.088 Y142.705 E38.5276
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.203 Y156.820 E39.4238
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.317 Y156.368 E39.4448
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X183.546 Y142.597 E40.3192
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X183.851 Y142.525 E40.3333
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X184.015 Y142.501 E40.3408
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.407 Y155.892 E41.1911
READ: ok T:264 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X197.488 Y155.408 E41.2132
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X184.507 Y142.427 E42.0375
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X184.799 Y142.383 E42.0507
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X185.015 Y142.369 E42.0604
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.539 Y154.893 E42.8557
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.582 Y154.370 E42.8793
READ: ok T:269 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X185.546 Y142.334 E43.6436
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X185.756 Y142.320 E43.6530
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X186.104 Y142.326 E43.6686
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.584 Y153.806 E44.3976
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.583 Y153.385 E44.4165
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.570 Y153.227 E44.4237
READ: ok T:270 @:0 B:0
SENT: G1 X186.680 Y142.336 E45.1152
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X186.715 Y142.337 E45.1168
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X187.305 Y142.397 E45.1434
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.518 Y152.609 E45.7919
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.503 Y152.430 E45.8000
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X197.422 Y151.947 E45.8220
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X187.962 Y142.487 E46.4227
READ: ok
SENT: M105
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X188.612 Y142.608 E46.4524
READ: ok
SENT: G1 X188.662 Y142.622 E46.4547
Total build time: 4.48 minutes
READ: ok
READ: ok T:269 @:0 B:0
SENT: M105
READ: ok T:267 @:0 B:0
SENT: M105
READ: ok T:270 @:0 B:0
SENT: M105
READ: ok T:270 @:0 B:0
Disconnected.
```

Answer (score 2):

What printer are you using? I had a friend who encountered this problem, at first we thought it was the slicer. Turns out, the wires for his extruder heater block and hot end fan were shorting, so whenever the extruder was turned on, it would keep heating no matter what the temp was set to. To test if this or something similar is happening, first unload your filament. Then, open up a small file in Simplify3D and set the temp to something low, like 100C. If the extruder turns on and just keeps heating, check your wiring. Make sure no wires are shorting and there are no bare/exposed connections.

Comment: Good point.  The other common error is connecting the bed thermistor to the extruder thermistor jack on the control board. Then the controller never "sees" the temperature on the extruder and madly keeps heating it.